# Under which account are web parts run?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

If I create some SharePoint Online web parts, are they run under the credentials of the user that is using the web part?
(this is what I would assume)

Say I need to make a query to the Graph API, would a SharePoint Administrator have more access that a standard cloud user?

Is there a way to run as a different user (one that has more privilege's)?

Thanks
P

```
var client = await this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3');
        
var result;
result = await client.api('groups/' + this.properties.groupGUID + '/members').get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPFX Webparts run in the context of the current logged in user. They will have all permissions the user is having. So if you are an admin, you will be able to do more stuff (if your webpart can do it) than as an user with "read" permissions.

If you want to do something with higher privileges you will have to use a backend like a custom API, Azure Functions or even Power Automate.

Answer (score 0):

SPFx web parts runs in the context of the current user and connection in the browser.

**Source**: [Key features of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

---

If you want to use MS graph in SPFx web part with specific permissions, you can request them from your web part.

when deploying the solution package to the app catalog, SharePoint creates permission requests and prompts the administrator to manage the requested permissions. For each requested permission, a global or SharePoint administrator can decide whether they want to grant or deny the specific permission. This will work for all users - SharePoint admin as well as normal users.

You can also use Application permissions and delegated permissions with Azure AD app registration.

Check below documentations for more understanding:

1. [Use Microsoft Graph in your solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-microsoft-graph-apis)
2. [Connect to Azure AD-secured APIs in SharePoint Framework solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient)
3. [Register an application with the Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2)
4. [Microsoft Graph permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference)